# I dont know why all of my links don't work

Tags: html, css

My links somehow broke. It have to redirect on youtube videos, but it haven't. And my button hover doesn't work. Help me please

```css
body {
  background: url("r.png");
  background-size: 10%;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.card {
  width: 225px;
  min-height: 225px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #ffff;
  z-index: -100;
}

.card_img {
  width: 225px;
  min-height: 225px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2.s;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px rgba(158, 34, 29, 0.185);
}

.card_top {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
}

.card_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.card_img>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card_img:hover>img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card_label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #ff6633;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 520;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_bottom {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.card_prices {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card_price {
  width: 50%;
}

.card_price::after {
  content: "\20B4";
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.card_price--discount {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #414141;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-style: italic;
}

.card_price--discount::before {
  content: "Зі знижкою";
  font-weight: 400px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_price--common {
  font-weight: 600px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #606060;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_price--common::before {
  content: "Звичайна ціна";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_title {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #414141;
}

.card_title:hover {
  color: #ff6633;
}

.card_button {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #70c05b;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #70c05b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.card_button2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #70c05b;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #70c05b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: -20px;
}

.card_button2:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #70c05b;
}

.card_button:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #70c05b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_cards {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 225px);
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  column-gap: 30px;
  row-gap: 40px;
}

.cards {
  padding: 75px 0;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Arial";
  top: -22px;
}

.sales {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Arial";
  top: -22px;
}

.shop_name {
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #501616;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.phone {
  width: 225px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  font-style: italic;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #703dc2;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sales">ШАЛЕНІ ЗНИЖКИ. ЧОРНА П'ЯТНИЦЯ</h1>
<section class="cards">
  <div class="container container_cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="shop_name">
        <h1 class="shop_name">Saharok.com</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card_top">
        <a href="1.html" class="card_img" target="_blank">
          <img src="33.png" alt="negros">
        </a>
        <div class="card_label">-10%</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_bottom">
        <div class="card_prices">
          <div class="card_price card_price--discount">14 000</div>
          <div class="card_price card_price--common">20 000</div>
        </div>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JOHMDCN3-E&ab_channel=Marakhonov" class="card_title" target="_blank">Маленьке гарненьке негритятко</a>
        <button class="card_button">У корзину</button>
      </div>
      <div class="phone">
        <h1 class="phone">+1-551-653-2938</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Open your dev console in the browser (F12) and select the network tab. What resources are downloaded and what errors do you get? my educated guess would be a 404 error as most likely the path is wrong.

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add `</div></div></section>` to make it valid.
The reason you links do not work is the -100 z-index in the .card  class. Remove that and the links will work

Comment: @tacoshy It is not a network issue. The links cannot be clicked at all

Comment: [Many more with the same issue](https://www.google.com/search?q=links+do+not+work+z-index+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: FWIW there is IMHO way too much CSS, some of which overrides prior values for the same class in a prior block of CSS  MORE CSS is most often a bad idea and paring it down to minimal should always be done.

Answer (score 0):

The original code snippet has the behavior of having a h1 tag that stays above the scrollable content at all times.

The issue is that links aren't clickable with the original code because the `.card` element has a `z-index: -100` to be below the h1 tag. Which houses the anchor tags.

The solution is to adjust the z-index of the elements that need to have precedence over one another:

```
.card {
  width: 225px;
  min-height: 225px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #ffff;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card .card_top a, .card .card_bottom a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sales {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Arial";
  top: -22px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Where the number of `z-index` adjusts the element visibility over another element. In the above case `.card` will have a lower visibility range than the h1 tag.

```css
body {
  background: url("r.png");
  background-size: 10%;
  background-position: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.card {
  width: 225px;
  min-height: 225px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #ffff;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card .card_top a, .card .card_bottom a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card_img {
  width: 225px;
  min-height: 225px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.2.s;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px rgba(158, 34, 29, 0.185);
}

.card_top {
  flex: 0 0 220px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
}

.card_img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.card_img>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.card_img:hover>img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card_label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: #ff6633;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 520;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_bottom {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.card_prices {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card_price {
  width: 50%;
}

.card_price::after {
  content: "\20B4";
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.card_price--discount {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #414141;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-style: italic;
}

.card_price--discount::before {
  content: "Зі знижкою";
  font-weight: 400px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_price--common {
  font-weight: 600px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #606060;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_price--common::before {
  content: "Звичайна ціна";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.card_title {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #414141;
}

.card_title:hover {
  color: #ff6633;
}

.card_button {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #70c05b;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #70c05b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.card_button2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #70c05b;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #70c05b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  bottom: -20px;
}

.card_button2:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #70c05b;
}

.card_button:hover {
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: #70c05b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_cards {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 225px);
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  column-gap: 30px;
  row-gap: 40px;
}

.cards {
  padding: 75px 0;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Arial";
  top: -22px;
}

.sales {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: grid;
  font-family: "Arial";
  top: -22px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.shop_name {
  width: 225px;
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #501616;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.phone {
  width: 225px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  font-style: italic;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #703dc2;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="sales">ШАЛЕНІ ЗНИЖКИ. ЧОРНА П'ЯТНИЦЯ</h1>
<section class="cards">
  <div class="container container_cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="shop_name">
        <h1 class="shop_name">Saharok.com</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card_top">
        <a href="1.html" class="card_img" target="_blank">
          <img src="33.png" alt="negros">
        </a>
        <div class="card_label">-10%</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_bottom">
        <div class="card_prices">
          <div class="card_price card_price--discount">14 000</div>
          <div class="card_price card_price--common">20 000</div>
        </div>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JOHMDCN3-E&ab_channel=Marakhonov" class="card_title" target="_blank">Маленьке гарненьке негритятко</a>
        <button class="card_button">У корзину</button>
      </div>
      <div class="phone">
        <h1 class="phone">+1-551-653-2938</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't fully fix the issue where it needs to be placed underneath the h1. It adds more issues for the user rather than helping... @mplungjan

Comment: Yes, I saw that too @mplungjan by just removing `z-index: -100` but the original HTML snippet needs the `.card` element to be scrollable but have a lower placement underneath the `h1` tag as you scroll. For aesthetic reasons I guess. I can still close the answer and post the fiddle as a comment!

Comment: Updated @mplungjan. Thanks for the insight. I am also learning...

Comment: So that part of the answer was not what was asked, but I will let it stand and not complain :)